# Length issue in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking an Ethical Hacking class, and my lab for the week is trying to crack passwords created by our professor. For this specific challenge, I used a 64 bit decoder to translate his string in his code, and have found the way to solve the problem.

The issue is when I run the equation found in the code, I run into an error in Python. I'll attach an image for clarification. I do know that length is typically found using len() but I don't know how to use that in this context. The part giving me issues is the [chunk2.length-1].

I was informed to add the errors I am receiving so here it is:

> you = chunk1[2+1]+d[1+1]+h[3]+chunk2[chunk2.length-1] AttributeError: 'str'
> object has no attribute 'length'

Any help provided would be great, thank you guys.

Comment: You can simply use `len(chunk) - 1` and  it  should work as expected. And for future reference, please copy and paste any code or errors you find and paste it directly in you question, it will make it easier and faster for use to answer your questions!

Comment: len(chunk) - 1 in place of [chunk2.length-1]? I'm very novice at Python in case it isn't obvious.

Comment: Yes that would have worked, your `chunk[-]` solution is definitely the simpler approach, wasn't paying enough attention to realize you were just trying to access the last element of the this

Answer (score 1):

I changed `chunk2[chunk2.length-1]` to `chunk2[-1]` and that solved my issue.